# Does the Macbook Air with flash memory have an SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, usb-flash-drive, macbook-air

The new Macbook Air uses flash memory and I'm just wondering if that means it has a solid state drive or is there a difference between the two?

Comment: And where in the list of Google results can one find out whether the flash memory a Macbook Air uses is just an SSD?

Comment: It can be inferred through its Wikipedia article, under the subsection *Flash memory as a replacement for hard drives*. (I don't agree with @Hello's method of conveying that information though)

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it uses a solid state drive, yes. The main component of a solid state drive is essentially a NAND-based **flash** memory. So it's basically the same.

Comment: what is NAND-based flash memory exactly

Comment: Well for that I'd probably just refer you to Wikipedia, as that's not really in the scope of this question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory

Comment: Thanks but just one more thing, is it the same thing or is there more to a SDD than just flash memory

Comment: Well flash memory is used inside the solid state disk. The disk adds, for example, a controller and the necessary ports. Another use would be USB sticks, for example.

Answer (score 0):

What "solid state" means is that there are no moving parts - that's all.  Any storage technology that does not use moving parts could be considered solid state.  Right now this is a new-enough concept that just saying a drive is "solid state" is enough, but as this very question indicates pretty soon we'll need to talk in terms of *what kind* of solid state drive you have.

So in this sense, yes, the mac book air flash storage is a solid state device.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the flash storage in the newest MacBook Air is in the form of flash chips on a custom card. So, unlike typical aftermarket SSDs for laptops, the MacBook Air's storage does NOT use the standard form factor of a typical 2.5" laptop SATA drive, nor does it follow the standard form factor of a 1.8" PCMCIA/PCCard/CardBus/ExpressCard hard drive, or any other standard hard drive form factor. You can't buy a standard form factor SSD drive and expect to be able to replace your MacBook Air's flash storage with it.